# How to configure and use sftp driver for storage on Laravel 10;

Tags: laravel, sftp

I'm writing a Laravel 10 project on PHP 8.2.
I need to access some file on an SFTP host.

I installed SFTP driver by

```
composer require league/flysystem-sftp-v3 "^3.0"
```

Then, here the configuration inside config/filesystems.php

```
    'sftp' => [
        'driver' => 'sftp',
        'host' => env('SFTP_HOST'),
     
        // Settings for basic authentication...
        'username' => env('SFTP_USERNAME'),
        'password' => env('SFTP_PASSWORD'),
     
        // Settings for SSH key based authentication with encryption password...
        'privateKey' => env('SFTP_PRIVATE_KEY'),
        'passphrase' => env('SFTP_PASSPHRASE'),
     
        // Settings for file / directory permissions...
        'visibility' => 'private', // `private` = 0600, `public` = 0644
        'directory_visibility' => 'private', // `private` = 0700, `public` = 0755
     
        // Optional SFTP Settings...
        'port' => env('SFTP_PORT', 6323),
        'root' => env('SFTP_ROOT', ''),
    ]
```

In addition I modified my .env file:

```
SFTP_HOST="my.host.it"
SFTP_USERNAME="mysftpusername"
SFTP_PASSWORD="mysftppwd"
SFTP_PRIVATE_KEY=""
SFTP_PASSPHRASE=""
SFTP_ROOT="/PagoPA/0000999/RT"
```

To test the sftp feature, I wrote a simple route

```
Route::get('test-sftp', function() {
    if (Storage::disk('sftp')->exists('RT_1000888_0000900_00000000000999999_250623160941-BNLIITRR-0597.xml')) {
        // ...
        return 'file found';
    } else {
        return 'file not found';
    }
});
```

The system return me the following error:

```
League\Flysystem\UnableToCheckFileExistence
Unable to check existence for: RT_1000888_0000900_00000000000999999_250623160941-BNLIITRR-0597.xml
```

Did I miss some configuration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue.

I simply had to remove these two lines from my .env file

```
SFTP_PRIVATE_KEY=""
SFTP_PASSPHRASE=""
```

In this way, the system uses the default null value for these parameters and it works like a charm.